# Time complexity of finding a string in an unordered set of strings

Tags: c++, string, stl, find, unordered-set

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/find/

The time complexity of find in an unordered_set has been given to be constant on average for an unordered_set.
If I have an unordered_set of strings, then what will be the time complexity of finding a string in that set?
Will it be constant or O(length of the string)?

Comment: [This is a better resource](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: The point is that cppreference.com is the more accurate and reputable source than the one you linked to.

Comment: *Will it be constant or O(length of the string)?* -- The hash of the string you're searching for has to be computed.  Look at the [std::hash<std::string>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash) implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::unordered_set` is implemented as a hash table.  Its `find` method has an average-case complexity of `O(1)` and a worst-case complexity of `O(set.size())` key comparisons as specified by [[tab:container.hash.req]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unord.req#tab:container.hash.req).

---

By default, `std::unordered_set<std::string>` uses `operator==` to compare keys, so each key comparison runs in `O(str.size())` as specified in [[string.view.ops]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.view#ops-13) (`operator==(const std::string&, const std::string&)` is defined to be equivalent to `std::string_view(str1) == std::string_view(str2)`, which is defined to be equivalent to `std::string_view(str1).compare(std::string_view(str2) == 0`).

For an `std::unordered_set<std::string>`, the container must calculate a hash of the string to find.  By default it uses `std::hash<std::string>` for this.  The standard doesn't specify any complexity requirements for `std::hash<std::string>`, but it's most likely `O(str.size())`.